# Visual Studio 2017 XAML designer for UWP is always loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I have just started working with Universal Windows Platform. I have upgraded to Win10 recently from Win7. I re-installed VS17 IDE and started working with UWP platform. However, when I try to open MainPage.xaml, the designer is always loading. The app builds correctly, though. In contrast, things go well with WPF and WinForms app designers.

I ran "ngen update /NoDependencies" ("ngen update" failed due to missing System.Web references) but that did not change anything.

My OS is brand new Windows 10 Fall Creators Upgrade (10.0.16299), so my UWP target version is the only possible one in the list. I can only change the Min Version.

Any advice would be grateful.

Comment: Whether the designer does not work even in a new blank UWP app? Could you try to repair the VS2017?

Comment: Yes, it does not work even in a new blank app. I am going to repair it but the IDE was installed just a week ago.

Comment: It still does not work. I uninstalled and reinstalled VS17 again, checked, repaired the program and nothing happens. Here is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/mfRVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial success.

The XAML works with Windows 10 Creators Upgrade (10.0.16299) SDK which I managed to install as an additional package.